# Finding all latlong inside a circle in google map

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4, google-maps-api-3

Lets assume i have center point LatLong saved in database and a given radius of 20 meters. and all the other LatLong near to this center place but not necessarily inside 20 meters of the center. Is there a way i can find all the latlongs inside 20 meters of radius from the center without rending a map. just using some api or mathematical formula?

Comment: How many are you wanting to get back?

Comment: how many i want back sorry i dont get you?

Comment: Instead of enumerating all possible coordinates which would populate tons of coordinates and likely you're not gonna use all of them, why don't you just calculate the frame of lat,lng from the given center and query the points from the database which lie within that frame instead?

Comment: @TaoP.R. I think when he says "all the latlongs inside 20 meters of radius" he means all the *stored* coordinates in his database. Not all possible points, which of course is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the markers in a loop and subsequently use the API function

```
computeDistanceBetween()
```

This will provide you the shortest distance which in Google API is called geodesic.

You can also use the function

```
computeLength()
```

Comment: This i for given point. the question is for getting point based on distance i think is the opposite

Comment: I understood the answer like, the lat-long are saved in the db, which would be the markers here. And the value of the functions gives the result in mts so by checking if it is in the range. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes your are  right is useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Haversine formula

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

this a good explanation

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

for JavaScript:

```
var R = 6371000; // metres
var φ1 = lat1.toRadians();
var φ2 = lat2.toRadians();
var Δφ = (lat2-lat1).toRadians();
var Δλ = (lon2-lon1).toRadians();

var a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
        Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
        Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

var d = R * c;
```

Whit this you can  iterate on your point and get if the distance is lower then 20 meters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a MySQL query (written in PHP) that allows you to retrieve all points within a given distance:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(" . $lat . ") ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(" . $lng . ") ) + sin( radians(" . $lat . ") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM your_table HAVING distance < 5";
```

Where `$lat` and `$lng` are the coordinates of your point, `lat`/`lng` are your table columns and `your_table` is your table name. The above will list the locations within a 5 nm range. Replace 3959 by 6371 to change to kilometers.

It uses the Haversine formula, as pointed by @scaisEdge in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pythagoras is adequate for less than 20 meters.

Below is javascript function to return distances in metres. I am sure you can convert to Java'

```
function Pyth(lat1,lat2,lng1,lng2){
x = toRad(lng2-lng1) ;
y = toRad(lat2-lat1);
R = 6371000; // gives d in metres
d = sqrt(x*x + y*y) * R;
return d;
}
```